# Sharepoint - Error: 500 Internal Server

Tags: c#, sharepoint, response

I have an error while getting access to a microsoft sharepoint website
i use a webservice, and the url should redirect me to the original page
(the page moved during a server migration). but when i get to this line

```
   HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

i get the error.

anyone have a suggestion for it?

mo

Comment: Is it your own SharePoint installation?

Comment: No, it's not my own sharepoint installation. The Sharepoint installation was developed by another company